# Why are member function pointers not accessed properly by corresponding members?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Consider this code snippet.

```
class B {
public:
    void up() {
        std::cout << "up" << std::endl;
    }
    void down() {
        std::cout << "down" << std::endl;
    }
    void init( void(B::*someFunc)() , void(B::*otherFunc)() ) {
        m_execute = someFunc;
        B* newB = new B();
        m_b = newB;
        m_b->m_execute = otherFunc;
    }

    void find() {
        (this->*m_execute)();
        (m_b->*m_execute)();
    }
private:
    void(B::*m_execute)();
    B* m_b;
};

int main(){
    B* b = new B();
    b->init(&B::up,&B::down);
    b->find();
}
```

I have a class B. Its private members are a pointer to B i.e. m_b and a function pointer.
In the init() function, private member function pointer is given up() and function pointer of private member m_b is given down()
When I run the code, B::up() is executed twice instead of executing B::up() and then B::down().

Comment: Maybe in the second line of `find()` you wanted `(m_b->*(m_b->m_execute))()` instead?

Comment: Typo. You are using the same member `m_execute` both times. It seems you want to write `(this->*m_execute)(); (m_b->*(m_b->m_execute))();`

Comment: Ah function pointers... aren't they just... fun :)

Comment: thanks guys... @NathanOliver haha..not always..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you apply one object's `m_execute` to another object.

Fix this by changing this line

```
(m_b->*m_execute)();
//     ^^^^^^^^^
// Points to your m_execute, not m_b's
```

to this:

```
(m_b->*m_b->m_execute)();
```

Better yet, add a member function to run your own execute, and call it from `B::find`:

```
void find() {
    run_my_execute();
    m_b->run_my_execute();
}
void run_my_execute() {
    (this->*m_execute)();
}
```

This would avoid the confusion on whose pointer should be applied to what object.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/TDEMu5)

Comment: Wow...Thanks...Had a lot work stuck because of this...But i still don't understand why it works. m_b is the child of B so why can't I simply use m_b->*m_execute , the same  way that I used it in init()

Comment: @RahulNaik, It's not about `m_b`, but `m_execute`. The syntax for calling a pointer to member function through an object pointer is `(ptr->*pmf)(...)`. In this case, the pointer to member function belongs to `m_b`, so you need to tell the compiler that: `(ptr->*(m_b->pmf))(...)`. Since `->` has higher precedence than `->*`, the extra parens are unnecessary. For you, `ptr` is `m_b` and `pmf` is `m_execute`.

Comment: @chris ohhhh...nice..didn't know about the precedence thing. Thank you

Comment: @RahulNaik `init` accesses `m_execute` members on two separate objects - its own in `m_execute = someFunc` and `m_b`'s in `m_b->m_execute = otherFunc`. Your `find()` member function has access to both these members as well, so it needs to specify which one it wishes to call.